# When Using Redux Saga with React Get This Error .. Uncaught TypeError: getPosts is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, dispatch

Trying to learn how to use Redux Sagas with React. Put together a simple example but it is not working for me.

My code in my App.js file:

```
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleWare();

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
)

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Action Creator:

```
 export const getPosts = () => {
        return  {
           type: 'GET_POSTS'
        }
     };
```

Reducer:

```
const combineReducers = (state= {}, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
       case 'GET_POSTS':
         return { ...state, loading: true};
       default:
         return state;
        }
      }

   export default combineReducers;
```

My Button component where the action should be called onClick

```
const ButtonContainer = (getPosts) => (
     <button onClick={() => getPosts()}>Get Posts</button>
)

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getPosts: getPosts
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ButtonContainer);
```

Problem is I get this error on page load.

```
Uncaught TypeError: getPosts is not a function....
```

Makes sense what the error is saying, it is getting the object instead of the function but not really sure what I need to do for this to work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have currently is not actually dispatching the getPosts action to your reducer.

Change you mapDispatchToProps to:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  getPosts: bindActionCreators(getPosts, dispatch)
}
```

You'll also need:

```
import { bindActionCreators, Dispatch } from "redux"
```

Also change your ButtonContainer to:

```
const ButtonContainer = props => (
     <button onClick={() => props.getPosts()}>Get Posts</button>
)
```

More info on dispatching can be found in [this](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#approaches-for-dispatching) good documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried the code above and now I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: getPosts is not a function. Any thoughts? In the mean time I am studying the link you posted above and trying to solve this issue.

Comment: I think its because your button component input parameter is the props not getPosts. Ive updated my answer.

Comment: OMG! dumb mistake, that solved it. Thank you  so much!

Comment: And you know what that was the main problem, I added props.getPosts and reverted back to my original code and it still works :-)

Comment: No problem @sayayin. Glad your problem is now fixed :)